# writing spacy(python) tokens to an excel file

Tags: python, spacy

I try to run the following code, which is about identifying subject from sentences and writing the subjects to an Excel file:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import spacy
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sub.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row=0
col=0
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
f=open("cdata.txt").read()
s=sent_tokenize(f)

for sent in sent_tokenize(f):
    worksheet.write(row, col, sent)
    doc=nlp(unicode(sent))
    print type(doc)
    for tok in doc:
        if tok.dep_=='nsubj':
             print type(tok)
             worksheet.write(row,col+1,tok)
```

but I keep getting the same error for the last line :

```
 TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'> in write()
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write that you want to write the subjects to the Excel file, but you are writing the full token. You should just write the tokens subject to the Excel cells:

```
            worksheet.write(row,col+1,str(tok._orth_))
```

the `str()` might not be necessary, but it cannot hurt.

You might also be able to do just `str(tok)`, especially if printing `tok` gets you the subject. Using `print()` automatically converts `tok` to a string, you have to do that explicitly when using `worksheet.write()`.